# Detect os Using tcp datagram

Tags: php, tcp, operating-system

After some research and about weeks of googgling I came to this question now:

How to implement the detection of remote OS of server using using tcp datagram information, in PHP?

Comment: Pardon? What information in which packets from which TCP-based protocol do you want to use to extract exactly what? Please show an example of how you will be receiving the packets and the structure of the packet, and what information you want to extract from it. If the information is in the TCP header, it's pretty much a complete non-starter with PHP.

Comment: After weeks of googling I'd have thought you'd have at least learned to spell it :0)

Comment: I just want to extract the os name like
Linux / Windows
@vascowhite Weak in english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can't analyse a TCP Datagram directly (if the connection is initiated from within PHP). You would need to either call upon an external tool (such as nmap) to do it for you, or have something call the script with the raw data contained within the packet.

Regarding nmap, you can read more about their fingerprinting methods [in this article](http://nmap.org/nmap-fingerprinting-article.txt), but to be honest it's normally fairly unreliable, especially if firewalls are involved on the connection. Of course there are also many tools for each OS that will actually hide the fingerprint on the server itself, thus not requiring network intervention to modify the packet, making it even more unreliable.

Comment: ok so i will need not to program it but need a third party script or something to do it.. yeah even i thought about it being unreliable . Thanks

Comment: Well PHP can't construct/read RAW packets, which is what you need as you will be reading the packet header. You will need a much more lower-level application to do this, or at least one which can pass the header/raw data back to your PHP script for processing.